# DatePicker (Jquery) in ListView(asp.net)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I need to put a datepicker in one of the columns in ListView. I have textbox for date but I don't know how to control it in Javascript and show the datepicker. I know Jquery has datepicker. Would be glad if someone could guide me on this. Thank you! Below is my designer code:

```
 asp:listview runat="server" ID="lsvPermits" 
             ItemPlaceholderID="itemApplication" DataKeyNames="PERMIT_TYPE_ID" style="width:100%">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table class="ListView_Style" cellspacing="0" border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse">
                    <tr class="ListView_Style ListView_HeaderStyle" >
                        <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPurchase" Suffix="?"
                                    Text="[Purchase?]"></asp:Label>                                    
                        </th>
                        <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPERMIT_TYPE_DESC" 
                                Text="[PERMIT TYPE DESCRIPTION]" >
                            </asp:Label>
                        </th>                                
                    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemApplication" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr runat="server" id="trItem" >
                    <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
                        <Asp:RadioButton runat="server" ID="rbtnPermit" />                                                                                               
                        <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
                             <%# CheckNull(Eval("PERMIT_TYPE_DESC"))%>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="middle" style="white-space: nowrap; text-align:center;">
                  <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                              
                        </td>   
                    </td> 
                </tr>
                <tr runat="server" ID="trMatchRow" >                           
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <EmptyDataTemplate>
                <table class="ListView_Style" cellspacing="0" align="left" rules="all" border="1"
                    style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <tr >
                        <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPurchase" Suffix="?"
                                    Text="[Purchase?]"></asp:Label>                                    
                        </th>
                        <th align="center" scope="col" style="width: 10%;">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblHeaderPERMIT_TYPE_DESC" 
                                Text="[PERMIT TYPE DESCRIPTION]" >
                            </asp:Label>
                        </th>           
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="MatchRow0">
                        <td style= "text-align:center;" colspan="8" class="hideBorder">
                            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblNoRecords" 
                                 Text="[There are no records to display]" >
                            </asp:Label>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </EmptyDataTemplate>
        </asp:listview>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I assume that you looking to have a date picker for txtDate?

Use the built in one - it is quite nice

So, then just add textmode to this:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" TextMode="Date">
 </asp:TextBox>
```

The result is then this:

[image]

Comment: Would you know how to change the date format into yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: You have to go into your regional settings, and change that format (so, the format will be whatever your computer is set to. For code behind you can (and will) always use the iso date format to set, such as yyyy-mm-dd. However, the format of the control client side is based on the users current regional settings.